# Why subview keep sticking to bottom and not adjusting according to parent UIView height

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I created a `UIView` and set its layout like this

[image]

And inside the above `UIView` I created another small `UIView` and set layout like this

[image]

I changed the height of `UIView` like this

[image]

but small `UIView` is not automatically adjusting according to its parent `UIView` height, it keep sticking to bottom. I want that small `UIView` always stick to its parent bottom what ever parent `UIView` height is. How can I do that?

Comment: is child view inside parent view?

Answer (score 0):

Constraints of `viewBlue`  is w.r.t. `ViewContainer` (VC's View)  not wrt `viewGreen`.

So do one of the follow :

1. Please check your view hierarchy in storyboard. Your `viewBlue` must be subview of `viewGreen`.
2. Right click on the `viewBlue` and drag it to `viewGreen`. This means you giving constraints to `viewBlue` wrt `viewGreen` . You get list of constraints that you can give wrt. Now give appropriate constraints which satisfy your conditions.

Comment: Yes it is a subview

Comment: @S.J Please check update answer. Pls show your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to make sure that your larger UIView contains the smaller view, as in the smaller one is contained in the larger one, then your constraints would be based on the larger view.

Your other, non - preferable option, is to give the smaller UIView a top constraint instead of a bottom constraint, and then it would be attached to the larger UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `subview` is inside `parent UIView` and then select both the views (subview and parentview), click on add new constraint at bottom right in Xcode as per given screenshot. You can place subview according to parent view's height, leading, trailing edges etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to place Small view inside of Large View and then give it bottom constraint to its parent (Large View).

[image]

Whenever you change the height from Large View, the small view inside it will move and stick to its parent bottom.